# Bad response to a BigQuery query: kind:discovery#restDescription instead of bigquery#queryResults

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery

I'm getting a response I'm totally not expecting to a query I'm doing from appengine.

Instead of a response with the kind  "bigquery#queryResults" which is expected according to the BigQuery docs, I'm getting

```
u'basePath': u'/bigquery/v2/', u'kind': u'discovery#restDescription',....
```

It seems to only happen with queries that would have taken 10-15 seconds and up, and I suspect this is some weird interaction with the Appengine dynamic 60 second timeout.

I'm running on python27, and use the google-api-python-client for the requests.

### Update

Tried a few other scenarios:

- running it on a backend - where no appengine request timeouts apply - same thing: ~9.8s into the request the discovery json is returned
- ran it in dev (localhost) again, to be sure: everything is fine
- **most interesting**, running it with with a shorter **timeout of 4s** (as opposed to 35s previously) results in the same discovery reply after the **same 9.8s** interval

Comment: Can you show us some of your code, and maybe a complete stack trace? This may point to a bug in the Python client library.

Comment: @JasonHall Is there something specific that interests you? Eventually it's just a service.jobs().query(...).execute() call which uses a server2server credential and otherwise works quite well. This happens on Appengine, not local dev server. I'm not sure which stack trace you mean - what I'm getting is not an exception, it's what gets returned from the call.

Comment: The `discovery#restDescription` comes from the Discovery API, which the Python client uses when you call `build()` to generate the methods to be able to call the BigQuery API. So it sounds like the response you're getting is from that Discovery API call and not the one to BigQuery.

Comment: That much I figured out on my own. The question is why this response instead of the one documented for the API I'm using, and if it indicates an error, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

From the App Engine [quota docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/quotas):

```
Each incoming HTTP request can be no larger than 32MB.
```

It might be possible that your queries are returning greater than 32 MB of data and this is causing HTTP 500 errors, resulting in the API providing the output you see above (which is the BigQuery API Discovery doc information - this response may be related to a separate issue with how the Python Client lib handles error responses on App Engine).

Suggested workaround: If your query responses are returning a great deal of data, you can use the [maxResults](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs/query) parameter to limit the amount of rows returned in a response page to a smaller amount. Then, you can make successive calls to the API to retrieve subsequent pages of data.

Comment: The responses are small - their size is independent of the size of the processes data.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known and fixed bug in the underlying httplib2 library.

Make sure you are using version 0.8 or later:

Check for in [httplib2/__init__.py](http://code.google.com/p/httplib2/source/browse/python2/httplib2/__init__.py):

```
__version__ = "0.8"
```