# Timeout on bigquery v2 from GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-api-python-client

I am doing a query to BigQuery from my app in google app engine, and receive a weird result from BQ sometimes (discovery#restDescription). It took me some time to understand that the problem occurs only when the amount of data i am querying is high, and thus making somehow my query time out within 10 sec.

I found a good description of my problem here:
[Bad response to a BigQuery query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13628104/bad-response-to-a-bigquery-query-kinddiscoveryrestdescription-instead-of-bigq)

After reading again GAE docs, i found out that HTTP requests should be handled within [***a few seconds***](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime#The_Sandbox). So i guess, and this is only a guess, that bigquery might also be limiting itself in the same way, and therefor, has to respond to my queries "within seconds".

If this is the case, first of all, i will be a bit surprised, because my bigquery requests are for sure going to take more than few seconds... But anyway, i did a test by forcing a timeout of 1 second to my query, and then get the queryResult by polling the API call getQueryResults.

The outcome is very interesting. BigQuery is returning something within 3 secs, more or less (not 1 as i asked) and then i get my results later on, within 26 secs by polling. This looks like circumventing the 10 secs timeout issue.

But i hardly see myself doing this trick in production.

Did someone encontered the same problem with BigQuery? What am i supposed to do when the query lasts more than "few seconds"?

Here is the code i use to query:

```
query_config = {
            'timeoutMs': 1000,
            "defaultDataset": {
                "datasetId": self.dataset,
                "projectId": self.project_id
            },
        }
query_config.update(params)
result_json = (self.service.jobs()
                       .query(projectId=project,
                       body=query_config)
                      .execute())
```

And to retrieve the results, i poll with this:

```
self.service.jobs().getQueryResults(projectId=project,jobId=jobId).execute()
```

And those are the logs of what happens on BigQuery:

```
2012-12-03 12:31:19.835 /api/xxxxx/ 200 4278ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.89 Safari/537.1
xx.xx.xx.xx - - [03/Dec/2012:02:31:19 -0800] "GET /api/xxxxx/ HTTP/1.1" 200 243 ....... ms=4278 cpu_ms=346 cpm_usd=0.000426 instance=00c61b117c1169753678c6d5dac736b223809b
I 2012-12-03 12:31:16.060
URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/bigquery/v2/rest?userIp=xx.xx.xx.xx
I 2012-12-03 12:31:16.061
Attempting refresh to obtain initial access_token
I 2012-12-03 12:31:16.252
URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/xxxxxxxxxxxx/queries?alt=json
I 2012-12-03 12:31:19.426
URL being requested: https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/xxxxxxxx/jobs/job_a1e74a6769f74cb997d998623b1b6b2e?alt=json
I 2012-12-03 12:31:19.500
```

This is what my query API call returns me. And in the meta data, status is 'RUNNING':

```
{u'kind': u'bigquery#queryResponse', u'jobComplete': False, u'jobReference': {u'projectId': u'xxxxxxxxxxx', u'jobId': u'job_a1e74a6769f74cb997d998623b1b6b2e'}}
```

with the jobId I am able to retrieve the results 26 secs later, when they are ready.

There must be another way! What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Note that your value for `timeoutMs` is 1000, or 1 second.